# How to add transition while navigating from one screen to other screen using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation to navigate from one screen to another screen. But while navigating I can see the navigation not good enough. So I am trying to add the transition while navigating from a screen to another screen. Any solution for this using react-navigation

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just use react-navigation then use the following [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/transitioner.html) 
you will have to use Transitioner

```
class MyNavView extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Transitioner
        configureTransition={this._configureTransition}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        render={this._render}
        onTransitionStart={this.onTransitionStart}
        onTransitionEnd={this.onTransitionEnd}
      />
    );
}
```

or

You can use the following third party library for the Transition in  navigation 
[Click Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-transitions)

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { fromLeft } from 'react-navigation-transitions';

const appStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA: {
      screen: ScreenA,
    },
    ScreenB: {
      screen: ScreenB,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ScreenA',
    transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(),
  },
);
```

Comment: I need a solution from react-navigation. Is any way there in react-navigation?. I did not prefer to add additionally a third-party package.

Comment: I have a clarification here, shall I need to add Transitioner component in all class or in only route file. Also does it make sense for this initialRouteParams: { transition: 'fade' },

Comment: please go through the following tutorial by Medium for complete understanding https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053